# get response from php and save in a file android

Tags: php, android, file, save, response

I'm trying to make a request from android to a PHP file. After that, i need to save the response generated by the PHP (a single code) into a file so i can read it next times without having to make the request again. For the request, i created a new method which reads as follows:

```
> private String deviceIdHttpGetter(){
>           HttpHandler handler =   new HttpHandler();
>           String code=handler.post("http://www.cafegourmet.es/newUser.php");
>           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your code is " + code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>               return code;
>               
>           }
```

I also moddified the HttpHandler post() method so i can get the code and return it, so now it looks like this:

```
>   public String post(String postURL){
>           try {
>               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
>               HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
>               HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
>               HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();
>               String text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
>               return text;
>           }
>     
>           catch(Exception e) { return e.getMessage();} 
>     }
```

The PHP, right now, reads as follows:

`<?php $code = 12345; echo $code; ?>`

Well... the problem is that, I don't know why, but I ALWAYS see the Toast as if no code were recieved ("your code is "), but when I access this PHP from the explorer, I always get the new code I need, therefore i cannot save the data to a file.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: Do you have the php file on a local server ?

Comment: In your post function, try returning something other than the empty string (like "error") in your catch block. That way you can tell the difference between an error in your try block and a blank response from the php page.

Comment: Did, It was returning "error" , and the Toast was showing "your code is error" back then. And no, the php is on a remote server. Adding the correct url to the code, if you want to check, it's an auto-increment int what it is returning right now

Comment: Okay, have it return `e.getMessage()` instead of `"error"` and post the error message it gives you

Comment: After some (stupid) editing, the code no longer throws the exception, but instead, returns not the code, so i guess that now the error is in the code of the Try. Updating the code right now, what i did is just include the String declaration inside the try, and supress the boolean as i'm no longer using it. i've been also checking, and, as the code returned by the PHP is an auto-increment int, it's like if it were not even doing the request.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-the-content-from-a-httpresponse-or-any-inputstream-as-a-string) example of reading contents of an `HttpResponse`

Comment: trying not to get crazy.... but this time the application went back to throwing the exception, and now if i use e.getMessage(), the application fails and shuts down, but not while using "error", don't get why... i'll check this example for reading contents and continue checking. i'll try to upload a video on youtube so you're able to see how it goes...

Comment: Have you tried just opening the page in a browser on the android device/emulator you are testing on?  It could be a networking issue that isn't allowing you to access the page and as a result the code above fails.

Comment: Yep, tried, and works perfectly. here's the link to the video. The first 4 seconds is using the APP with the "e.getMessage()", then you can jump to the 38s and see what happens when using the "error" string in the return... i think it's kinda weird...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=DN7tH11-59E

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DN7tH11-59E 


(Incorrect Link)

Comment: Partially solved. Instead of using e.getMessage(), I used e.toString() and got the exception. Exception on main thread was thrown, so, instead of using an HttpHandler, I had to use an AsyncTask, now I need to read from the AsyncTask....

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAnd it's done!, gonna post the code updated for if it helps someone^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code with the problem solved, hope it helps someone:

First, the code for calling the async in the main activity reads as following:

```
private String deviceIdHttpGetter(){
        try
        {
        AsyncHttpDeviceId asyncId = new AsyncHttpDeviceId();
        return asyncId.execute("http://www.cafegourmet.es/newUser.php").get();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Async finally reads as following:

```
public class AsyncHttpDeviceId extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String code="";

     public AsyncHttpDeviceId () {
        }

        /**
         * background
         */
     protected String doInBackground(String... posturl ) {
               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpResponse response;
               String responseString = null;
               try {
                   response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(posturl[0]));
                   StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                   if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                       ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                       response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                       responseString = out.toString();
                       out.close();
                   } else{
                       //Closes the connection.
                       response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                       throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                   }
               } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                   return e.toString();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   return e.getMessage();
               }
               return responseString;
      }
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            code=result;
      }
}
```

Hope this helps someone someday.